# How can I apply `(toggle-debug-on-quit)` ignore ` Debugger entered Lisp error: (minibuffer-quit)`

Tags: minibuffer, debug, quitting

I have `(toggle-debug-on-quit)` in my `init.el` file due to find a issue that makes emacs hangs. But it also catches `minibuffer-quit`.

Would it be possible to *ignore* catched errors for `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (minibuffer-quit)`?

To generate `minibuffer-quit` error:

```
M-x
C-g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `minibuffer-quit` to `debug-ignored-errors`.

You can do this using:

```
(add-to-list 'debug-ignored-errors 'minibuffer-quit)
```

Comment: How can I add `minibuffer-quit` into `debug-ignored-error`? Is this the way:  `(setq debug-ignored-errors 'minibuffer-quit)`?

Comment: @alper, I've updated the answer.